# Mapbox offline map loading issue

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, offline

I am working with the map application. In my application, I have to give support of offline map. 
I go through many examples and tutorial of **mapbox**.

I found the code of how to download the offline map. But didn't find how to load that different downloaded map in mapbox.

For offline map download, I refer to this link [download offline map.](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/offline-pack/)

But, How to load different downloaded map pack in mapbox.

Comment: Map box does it automatically. If you try to access a part of the map you have downloaded when you are offline it will simply show your offline map tiles.

Comment: @Magnas: I don't think so. Let me explain the case. 
-- I downloaded multiple regions one is from new york, one is from the UK.
-- Now in my phone there is no internet. Which map is load in mapbox and how mapbox manage which to load?

Comment: The offline map won’t show in the Mapbox mapview until you tell it to display a location contained in your offline maps. They don’t automatically appear. If you tell the mapview to display New York or the coordinate of the Empire State Building you should see your offline map for New York. If you want to see the map in the UK you have to tell the mapview to show that area.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had one more query related mapbox. Mapbox also cache map without download it. When user is offline mapbox load map automatically, Right? But how I know that mapbox map load from cached map or downloaded map.

Comment: I don’t think any information about the cached maps is available to the user. It is completely transparent. The cache is unpredictable since you don’t ever know how many map tiles have been cached or when the cache will be flushed. If you wanted to test your offline map and make sure the cache is not involved, delete your app and reinstall it fresh from XCode so that the cache is empty.